# MpAndroidChart bug: Line chart fill color on pre API 21 devices

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I have found this problem:[image]

The fill color does not follow the data.

This is the method that causes problem in my pre lollipop device.

```
dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
```

In a device with api 21+ all works.

Code:

```
            LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");

            dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
            dataSet.setFillAlpha(255);
            dataSet.setFillColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_primary_color));
```

If there is a workaround until the fix please let me know it because it's really ugly to see the chart without a Fill color.

EDIT:
I've tried and it works also in emulator with API 15.
The problem happen in my real samsung 4 mini with android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line(worked for me):

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            mChart.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(false);
        }
```

See https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1100

Here they talk about performance:https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1189

Answer (score 0):

Use dataSet.setFillFormatter to set a custom fill.

Comment: This don't solve the problem. Moreover I don't want a custom fill but the default one.